# Simultaneous representations of elements of projective tensor products

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, tensor-products

Let $E,F$ be Banach spaces and consider the projective tensor product $E \widehat\otimes F$.  If $\tau \in E \widehat\otimes F$ with $\|\tau\|<1$ then by definition we can find $(x_n)\subseteq E$ and $(y_n)\subseteq F_n$ with
$$ \tau = \sum_n x_n \otimes y_n \qquad \sum_n \|x_n\| \|y_n\| < 1. $$

Now suppose $T,S$ are (bounded) operators on $E, F$ respectively, so that $T\otimes S$ acts on $E \widehat\otimes F$.  Suppose $\|(T\otimes S)\tau\| < 1$ as well as $\|\tau\|<1$.  Can we find a representation $\tau=\sum_n x_n\otimes y_n$ with both
$$\sum_n \|x_n\| \|y_n\| < 1 \qquad \sum_n \|T(x_n)\| \|S(y_n)\| < 1? $$

Motivation: I am mostly interested in the case when $E=F$ is a Hilbert space, and $T=S^{-1}$ is a positive (perhaps unbounded) operator.  This is motivated by looking at automorphism groups of C$^*$-algebras.

Comment: Do we at least know this for $E=F=\ell_1(J)$, where in some sense we know the "best" representation for elements of $\ell_1(J)\widehat\otimes\ell_1(J) \cong \ell_1(J\times J)$